# Nuxt + Netlify Forms custom success page not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify

I have a simple Form in my Nuxt Project - hosting on Netlify and use the Netlify Forms feature - docs here https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/

```
  <form
    action="/confirm" name="request" method="post" data-netlify="true" netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
  >
    <p class="hidden">
      <label>Don’t fill this out if you're human: <input name="bot-field" ></label>
    </p>
    <v-text-field
      label="Name"
      name="name"
    />
    ...
    <v-btn
      :disabled="!valid"
      type="submit"
    >send
    </v-btn>
  </form>
```

If I browse to https://mddomain.com/confirm it works fine.

If I submit the form on the first time I come to the /confirm page but Netlify doesn't safe the data. If i try it again I got this Error Mesage:

> Page Not Found
>   Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.
>
> Back to our site

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Were you able to find a resolution for this issue? I am running into the same and unable to fix it.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have the same issue. I've added the hidden input field `form-name` with the same value as the name attribute on the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `nuxt.config.js` has `mode: 'universal'` and NOT `mode: 'spa'`.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding the `<input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="NAME_OF_YOUR_FORM" />` to the form, that netlify creates automatically  if missing, solved the issue.

It has to do with the Vue/Nuxt routing. My form was working if I'd navigate directly to my contact page, or refresh the page, but **not** when going over the navigation of my site, that consists of `<NuxtLink>`'s. And although you find the answer deep inside their forum and so many Nuxt users having problems with the form, they haven't added that as hint to the form documentation.